# if statement not executed in JSP scriptlet

Tags: mysql, database, jsp

i encountered the following problem. I have made a table in mysql named 'users' and i want to add users using JSP. The primary key is the Email and i want to check before adding another user if the email already exists. If the email already exists the users will not be added to the database and a message "email already exists" will appear.

I created ResultSet rs object and extracted the "Email" column into a String email using a while loop.Now, here comes the problem. Suppose i have a user with the "denis@yahoo.com" email. If i try to add an user with the exact same email an error will occur which means my if statement was ignored. I looked up in the debug mode for the variables email and Email and they had the exact same    "denis@yahoo.com" and still the if statement was ignored.

```
<!-- file name: addUser.jsp -->
<%  
        String Email=request.getParameter("Email");
        String Name = request.getParameter("Name");
        String Adress = request.getParameter("Adress");
        String Phone = request.getParameter("Phone");
        if (Email != null) 
        {
             jb.connect(); // connect to the database using JavaBean class
             ResultSet rs;
             rs=jb.seeTable("users");// rs gets first row of table
             String email;
             int a=1;
            while(rs.next())
            {
                email=rs.getString("Email");
                if(Email==email)
                {
                    a=0;
                    jb.disconnect();

 %>
             <p> The email already exists</p>

             <% 
                 break;
                }
            }
              if(a==1){
            jb.addUser(Email,Name, Adress, Phone);
            jb.disconnect();

             %>

    <p>Data has been added.</p>

   <%
    }

         } else {

   %>


    <form action="addUser.jsp" >

       Email:  <input type="text" name="Email"><br>
       Name:  <input type="text" name="Name"><br>
       Adress: <input type="text" name="Adress"><br>
       Phone: <input type="text" name="Phone"><br>
       <button type="submit" >Add User</button><br>
    </form>

<%
}
%>
```

I use NetBeans IDE 8.2, and something that i think is odd appeared in the debug mode. One of the email i try to test appeared with bold characters meanwhile the other was not bold.

Why is my if statement ignored if i add an user with the exact same email of another? Please help me out!

Comment: Change `if(Email==email)` to `if(Email.equals(email))`. String comparison can't be done with `==`

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much!